# solve equations with n variable and m unknown using matlab

Tags: matlab, variables

I want to solve equations with n variable and m unknown in matlab;
first I produce n variable using below code:

```
 clear;close all;clc;
M=rand(10,3);
x=M(:,1);y=M(:,2);z=M(:,3);
fu=[];
syms B0 B1 B2 e 

for i=1:10
eval(['fu' '= B0+B1*x+B2*y+e-z'])  
end
```

now I have 10 variable and 4 unknown that they are `B0,B1,B2,e`

I want to solve this equations,
using `solve`:

```
solve('fu=0','B0','B1','B2','e')
```

but i see error
how can I solve this?

Comment: what error do you see?

Comment: I mean that I cane take answer.
is any proposed method for solving this variations?

Comment: There might not be an answer - you have just assigned random numbers into your equations so there's no guarantee that a solution will be found.

Comment: ok, I know but it was for represent.
I have x,y and z, I mean that can I give a serious answer? because number of my variables are more than unknown?

Comment: How are you expecting to solve for both `B0` and `e`? It's no wonder if falls over, no matter what your `x,y,z` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have 10 equations for four unknowns doesn't mean that a) there is a solution which fits all of them exactly and b) that MATLAB can find it.  `solve` is most definitely not the best tool for all cases.

If you want a numerical solution you could use `linsolve`. Each of your equations can be written in the following form (I have incorporated e and B0 into a single constant value, B0, as there is no way of solving for both if neither is known):

```
B0*1 + B1*x + B2*y = z
```

You construct a matrix of 1, x, and y values:

```
M = [ones(length(x),1),x,y]; 
B = linsolve(M,z);
```

B should be a vector of three numbers - these are your `B0`, `B1` and `B2`.  `M*B` should return approximately `z` (for the random number case it's not very good).